# Способы правильной организовки авторизации без session в Node.js/express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Сейчас я работаю над приложением express.js, в котором пользователь может зарегистрироваться/авторизоваться, после чего создается его профиль, он может добавлять посты, и комментировать чужие. И вот у меня появилась мысль на счёт авторизации пользователя:

(Я использую базу данных MongoDB, при регестрации, создается уникальный id пользователя, напимер: id: 5445b43d258346623c56748e)

1. Когда пользователь авторизовался, отправляется запрос в базу данных, что бы найти пользователя.
2. Если он найден, в cookies браузера записывается id найденного пользователя.

Теперь, при запросе к серверу, пользователь будет идентифицирован по id.
Я знаю что существуют сессии, популярные способы хранения данных сеанса это: **Хранение в памяти приложения, В кеш-памяти, В базе данных.** Я хочу обойтись без этих способов, так как мой кажется намного проще. Если учитывать проблемы с безопасностью, то это подмена id в куках, но в моем случае с этим проблем быть не должно, так как генерируемый id мне кажется длинным, и подобрать его сложно?

Вопрос в том, корректно ли использовать данный метод? И безопастно ли? Просто везде, если речь идёт об авторизации, все говорят использовать сессии, но что если обойтись без них? Я так же не понимаю, какие минусы, в данном методе? Может нужно как-то улучшить добавляемый в куки id, например как-то хешировать, добавив к нему пароль + имя пользователя + соль?

Буду очень рад, если кто-то объяснит.)

Comment: Да, хранение в открытом виде ID пользователя, а затем использование его и только его для идентификации пользователя - дыра. Вам кажется что длинный и не подбираемый - ну так есть способы не сгенерировать, а своровать этот ID из сессии чужого пользователя. Я бы предложил не мучаться и использовать для сессий стандартный механизм сессий :) Он отлажен, проверен и отточен. Ну ладно... Как вариант можете попробовать JWT, его тоже можно для сессий использовать, хотя многие считают, что не стоит. То, что вы описали с хешированием, солью и т.п. - заного придумали JWT

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ, стандартный механизм сессий, это какой именно?)

Comment: в вашем случае express-session пакет можно использовать, собственно вы его и описали

Comment: Да, читал о нём, но ведь бъект node.js сессии глобальный и будет перезаписываться данными последнего пользователя? И в итоге нужно будет использовать хранилище оперативной памяти, например MemCached или Redis? Если что не так говорю, простите, только не давно к этому пришёл, возможно вопросы кажутся глупыми...)

Comment: ну я использовал в связке с Redis, с MongoDB похожий принцип будет - данные о сессии сохраняются в БД с некоторым временем жизним когда авторизуется пользователь. а затем при обращении авторизованного пользователя смотрится id сессии, берутся данные из БД по этому ключу и используются для дальнейшей обработки. я не очень понял, что за глобальный обьект вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Тоесть, при создании сессии с помощью express-session, нужно в качестве параметра `store` указать базу данных? Или для этого есть специальные пакеты?

Comment: читайте документацию, там все описано. а так да, при инициализации модуля сессий в коде указывается какое хранилище будет использоваться и как будут работать сессии. для каждой БД есть дополнительный пакет.
вот тут огромный список, чего только нет https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores
Для Mongo там два пакета, один популярный с поддержкой mongoose, второй не популярный, но зато напрямую с монго работает без mongoose вроде

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли, буду разбираться)